# Popular dados programaticamente x manualmente

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Você pode popular dados de um componente em **.NET** utilizando interface do Visual Studio *(Selecionar DataSource...).*

- Do ponto de vista de performance popular dados via código é mais rápido que manualmentr?

Comment: Acho que tu queres dizer "acoplar" a invés de "copular", não?

Comment: Ou talvez, mais provavelmente, "popular" dados? hahaha

Comment: @LuizVieira Corrigido, eu sempre me confundo! Obrigado.

Comment: @Laerte Sem erro. Ao menos garantiu umas boas risadas né? :) Ah, faltou corrigir no corpo do texto.

Comment: @LuizVieira Corrigi! O que importa é aprender, errar faz parte do processo! Valeu!

Comment: É, a menos que a pergunta seja sobre [algoritmos genéticos](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_gen%C3%A9tico), creio que cópula de dados não faz muito sentido... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não deve existir diferença. O que o Visual Studio faz quando você seleciona um DataSource através de sua interface gráfica é gerar o código de associação de forma automática. Você mesmo poderia escrever esse código. Só haverá diferença de performance se você estiver montando seu DataSource manualmente e de alguma maneira ineficiente.

Se você tem a expectativa de que o banco de dados mude, o melhor é abstrair o máximo possível a construção do DataSource. É preferível também deixar os dados da conexão em um arquivo de configuração, nesse caso. Ou em algum outro lugar no qual você possa alterar esses dados facilmente sem ter que recompilar o programa.

Answer (score 2):

Laerte, quando você popula seus DropDown via código, você ganha em questão de abstração, pois você pode desacoplar a regra de negócio vinda do banco através do DataSource.

Por exemplo, se você tiver uma aplicação hoje em um banco SQL Server e amanhã descobre que precisa migrar o banco para um Oracle e não mexer em sua estrutura das tabelas, se você popular por DataSource todos seus DropDown, quando fizer a migração, terá que refazê-los na mão para utilizar outro provider. Se você fizer via código, com uma arquitetura bem estruturada e separada e utilizando uma camada de acesso a dados genérica, você quase não terá que mexer em seu código, dependendo até mesmo por exemplo de ORM que utilizar, talvez seja precisa apenas mudar o caminho de conexão do banco de dados.